# Cygwin doesn't see header file when building in Netbeans

Tags: c++, netbeans, cygwin

I created a class through Netbeans and it made a .cpp and .h file.
I included the .h in my main.cpp but when I build the project it fails saying it cannot find the .h file even though they're in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure to actually include the file in your project folder where your main.cpp and other files are kepted?

Comment: I used File -> New File -> C++ Class and it put it in the same directory as main.cpp

Comment: yeah theres a projects block on the left side of the netbeans screen under your project there should be source files folder and header files folder did you make sure to right click the header files folder and included that? or it could just be your path isn't set in your configuration setting

Comment: What do I click to include it?

Answer (score 0):

I went to the project properties and added the root of the project as an Include directory and it's working fine now.

Comment: I actually found the real reason it wasn't working... I surrounded the .h file with <>, not ""